# Prove that if $f$ is derivable in an interval $I$ and $f'(a)=0$ and $f''(a) \ne 0$, then $a$ must be a local minimum or maximum of the function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives, continuity

> Let $I$ be an interval and $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function derivable in all points of $I$. Let $a$ be an interior point of $I$ such that $f'(a)=0$ and $f''(a) \ne 0$. Show that $f$ has local minimum or maximun on $a$.

Suppose $f''(a)>0$. The opposite situation is similar.

Let $a_n \in I$ be a sequence such that $a_n \rightarrow a.$ Let $b_n$ be  the subsequence with elements $a_n>a$ and $c_n$ the sequence with elements $a_n<a$. Since $a_n \rightarrow a$ then $b_n\rightarrow a$ and $c_n \rightarrow a$.

$f''(a) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f'(a_n)-f(a)}{a_n-a} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f'(b_n)-f(a)}{b_n-a} $ (and the same for $c_n$).

Let $0<\epsilon<f''(a). \exists N \in \mathbb{N}\; s.t. \; \forall\; n\geq N$
$$ f''(a)-\epsilon\leq\frac{f'(b_n)-f'(a)}{b_n-a}\leq f''(a)+\epsilon\implies f'(b_n)-f'(a)>0\implies f'(b_n)>0$$

The same argumentation will get that $f'(c_n)<0$.

That means that for every $b_n$ exists and $\delta$ such that $\forall x \in [b_n-\delta,b_n]\cap I ;f(x)<f(b_n)$ and for every $c_n \exists \; \mu\; s.t.\; \forall x \in [c_n,c_n+\mu]; f(x)>f(c_n)$.

That concludes that $a$ is a local minimum (if we suppose $f''(a)<0$ we will get that $a$ is a local maximum).

> My doubt is:Showing the derivatives of the values below $a$ are less than $0$ and those above $a$ are greater  really proves that $a$ is minimum? Or can the function somehow zigzag near $a$ so even with derivatives in the sequence being greater/lower then $0$ the function still doesn't have local minimum in $a$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that since

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{x-a} \neq 0$$
and the limit exists, the fraction

$$\frac{f'(x)}{x-a}$$ is the same sign in some neighbourhood of $a$. Suppose it's positive (the negative case is similar). Then, *in this neighbourhood*, we can deduce the following:

For $x>a$, $f'(x)>0$ and from the mean value theorem for $x>a$, $f(x) > f(a)$, and similarly for$x<a$, $f'(x) < 0$ which implies $f(a) < f(x)$ for $x<a$. Thus $f(a)$ is a local minimum.